# Reset bootstrap-session-timeout without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, session

We are using the Orangehill fork of bootstrap-session-timeout and it works nicely, with one exception, and I cannot figure out how to reslve this. Wondered if someone could help turn the light on for me.

Site is written in PHP with Bootstrap3 and JQuery3.

The footer of every page contains the script that activates bootstrap-session-timeout, but the option to reset the timer each time the mouse is moved is not used. If there is no activity within the timeout period, the ribbon pops up and the user is given the option of Staying Connected or Signing Out.

This is working fine for the site, however what we have is an order edit page, where users can add, delete and update lines that are on an order. The page is not refreshed during the edit. To add, delete or update order lines, the links call JS functions, which in turn call PHP scripts to perform the updates, JS then being used to update the screen contents dynamically.

We need to reset the session timeout counter each time the user updates the order.

Ideally, we would like to call a function whenever an update to the page contents is made, but none of the individual bootstrap-session-timeout functions seem to be available within our JS.

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance for any help/pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody responded to this question, I thought it pertinent to add my solution, which might not be the best, but it does work.

Basically, we have an order entry page which stays in place while an order is being entered. The countdown timer keeps going even though the user might be doing something on the page (we have the on-key options turned off). So, even though the user might have last updated the order 5 minutes ago (the updates being handled via Ajax calls to PHP API's), the countdown timer is not reset because the page has not been reloaded.

My solution is to write the timestamp to a file which is keyed by PHP session-id, every time a PHP script is loaded. This applies to the main page or to API's.  So, when the countdown timer ends, a timeout script is called, and this checks whether the last activity timestamp in the file is before or after the timeout cutoff point.  If it is, the logout script is called, but if not, the current page is refreshed, which causes the countdown timer to be reloaded.